# Book reference for neural networks and deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

What would be a good text reference for neural networks and machine learning that does not shy away from math?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references+neural-networks

Answer (score 2):

- In terms of general ML, the [Elements of Statistical
  Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie
  et al. or [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/people/cmbishop/prml-book/) by Bishop.
- In terms of Deep Learning (and Neural Networks), the [Deep
  Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org) book by Goodfellow et al.  or [Neural Networks and Deep Learning: A Textbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319944623) by Aggarwal.

Comment: I am currently reading the deep learning book, but sometimes it seems very loose on details. Is there any other similar book?

Comment: I think it depends which part. [Neural Networks and Deep Learning: A Textbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319944623) by Aggarwal is also considered good but I have not read it.

Comment: I am in the middle of chapter 6, there are many cool insights such as viewing the loss function as a functional and other things, however there seems not to be any mathematical develpment of those ideas.